# Keep primefaces poll from closing a dialogue

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF & Primefaces.

I have a dashboard with a few datatables and panels that gets populated with dynamic data via a poll.

Under the one datatable I have made the dynamic data commandlinks which opens a dialogue with more in-depth data.

The only problem is each time the poll fires off, the dialogue closes.

Solutions I have tried is making a boolean value and function in my bean to start and stop the poll, but I am unsure where to specify the poll to stop. onHide for the dialogue doesn't work.

Is there a value I can use for the dialogue to either stop it from being closed, or to call the startPoll function? I want the poll to keep running all the time or have it stop when the dialogue opens, and start back up when it closes.

Any solution that stops the dialogue from being closed by the poll would be perfect.

Comment: if the poll doesn't have to update the dialog on the page, place the dialog outside the update container

Comment: Hatem is spot on. If you need to update dialog content as well, place a tag with id inside a dialog `<h:panelGroup id="content">...` and update it. otherwise use [Primefaces Selectors](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf) to exclude the dialog from update.